# DJANGO: How to serialize form values into json for storage in a database column

Tags: json, django, forms, serialization

I am working on a project and i am required to store information entered into a form to a database column as json. The form does not have a model of its own but all its values will be stored as json into a column of another model. Here is the model:

```
class Document(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    document = models.JSONField(default = {})
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Now i am required to store json data from different forms (different `category`s ) into the column `document`. Here is one category of such forms:

```
class InformalLetterForm(forms.Form):
    sender_name = forms.CharField(max_length=45)
    sender_address = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
    date = forms.DateTimeField()
    message_body = forms.CharField()
    receiver_name = forms.CharField(max_length=255)
```

How do i serialize data entered in such a form to a json object to be stored in a database column (i.e the column `document` above).

i have searched online but i have seen serialization done only for data from model forms.
Thanks for any help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call the [`.cleaned_data`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form.cleaned_data) attribute from the Form, it will return a dictionary with the form's data in python, then you can call the [`.dumps()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) method from `json` python's library. Let's take an example from the docs:

```
>>> data = {'subject': 'hello',
...         'message': 'Hi there',
...         'sender': 'foo@example.com',
...         'cc_myself': True}
>>> f = ContactForm(data)
>>> f.is_valid()
True
>>> f.cleaned_data
{'cc_myself': True, 'message': 'Hi there', 'sender': 'foo@example.com', 'subject': 'hello'}
```

Here you have a dictionary with your data, now let's make it a json:

```
import json

# An example simple dict
d = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}

json.dumps(d)

# '{"a": 1, "b": 2}'
```